# CType-uploads: Wrong sorting of special characters like "ä"

Tags: sorting, utf-8, typo3

In a TYPO3 11.5.30 system I set the content type element "uploads" to sort the filelinks by the metadata field "title". But there seems to be a problem with the collation. Files with an "Umlaut" as first letter are always listed at the end of the list.

The collation, checked via phpmyadmin, of all database tables is "utf8mb4_unicode_ci". This collation should cause the right order, but obviously I'm doing something wrong. Any help?
Thank you so mutch

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into the `Configure Installtion-Wide Options` (Install-Tool):

There is an option `[SYS][UTF8filesystem]`:

> If TRUE then TYPO3 uses utf-8 to store file names. This allows for
> accented Latin letters as well as any other non-latin characters like
> Cyrillic and Chinese. IMPORTANT: This requires a UTF-8 compatible
> locale in order to work. Otherwise problems with filenames containing
> special characters will occur. See [SYS][systemLocale] and
> setlocale().

Comment: Many thanks for your quick answer! But the [SYS][UTF8filesystem] = true an [SYS][systemLocale] is set to de_DE.utf8.

Comment: as TYPO3 stores the filenames in the database the sorting might depend on the sorting there. is it `latin2_general_ci` or something general like: `utf8mb3_general_ci` (the collation may be assigned to any level of server, database, table, field)